# How to send variables from javascript to php properly with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, postgresql

I want to send a string variable from javascript to php, and use the string variable as a key value to set the database(pgsql). Here are the related codes.

from javascript:

```
    $scope.check = function(name) {
    var checkstatus = true;

    console.log(name);
    console.log(typeof name);
    if (document.getElementById(name).value == "true") {
        document.getElementById(name).value = "false";
        console.log("uncheck!");
        checkstatus = false;
    } 
    console.log(checkstatus);
    if (checkstatus === false) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'partials/reception/deleteFromCheckedList.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'name': name
            },
            success: function (response, xhr) {
                location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

from php:

```
include('../get/inc/db.php');
$connect=pg_connect("host=$hostname dbname=$database user=$user 
password=$password");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query="UPDATE images SET active='0' WHERE \"fileName\" LIKE '" . $name . "'";
$result=pg_query($connect, $query) or die ("Error in 
Query:$query.".pg_last_error($connect));
```

In javascript file, the type of variable is string.
In php, the type of column "fileName" is character varying.
When running the code above, the data of "active" do not have any change. However the web page will refresh every time I change the check status in javascript. I can not figure out why this will happen.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, [my name is](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) `'; drop table images; --`

Comment: You must validate and sanitize your $_POST variables in your php file or the above will happen.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the problem. It is because I run this code on local server on mac. It might be problematic to use the local server. When I upload it to the server where database is located on linux system, the problem solved.